# Custom workflow activity - return collection or array?

Tags: list, android-activity, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

For MS CRM 2011 I have made custom workflow activity, but I'm not able to register it, because as an output parameter I'm trying to return

```
OutArgument<IEnumerable<EntityReference>>
```

which is propably not supported.

How can I return the collection or an array of entity refereces?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is list of supported types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx) you can return on a custom workflow. Unfortunately `IEnumerable` is not on the list :(

Answer (score 0):

at best you can define one reference at a time :

```
    [Input("EntityReference input 1")]
    [Output("EntityReference output 1")]
    [ReferenceTarget("account")]
    [Default("3B036E3E-94F9-DE11-B508-00155DBA2902", "account")]
    public InOutArgument<EntityReference> AccountReference { get; set; }

    [Input("EntityReference input 2")]
    [Output("EntityReference output 2")]
    [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
    [Default("4C036E3E-94F9-DE11-B508-00155DBA2902", "contact")]
    public InOutArgument<EntityReference> AccountReference { get; set; }
```

Supported parameters are:

```
• Bool
• DateTime
• Decimal
• Double
• EntityReference
• Int
• Money
• OptionSetValue
• String
```